# Entity Framework 6: "No connection string could be found in the application config file." when referencing .net framework dll in asp.net core app

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, entity-framework-6

I'm porting an ASP.NET MVC application to .NET Core.

One of the apps dependencies is a .NET Framework dll that uses Entity Framework 6.
I added the settings from the old ASP.NET MVC app and referenced `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` to use the old settings file format in the new app.

When I run the app I get an error:

> No connection string named="myEntity" could be found in the application config file.

How do I add the connection string to my new .NET Core app?

Comment: You need to add the connection string in the settings.json file.  The pass the connectrion string in the DB Context Constructor

Comment: the constructor of my dbContext don't receive parameters. If i change it and then update the edmx file it will auto generate it again and will delete the change ill make to the constructor

Comment: Check my answer I show you how to modify your t4 template to pass the connection string in the base constructor

Answer (score 2):

Add you connection string to your appsettings.json like this:

```
"Data": {        
    "DB": "metadata=res://*/AppDB.csdl|res://*/AppDB.ssdl|res://*/AppDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='Your Connection String Goes Here'",       
  },
```

Read your connection string like this:

```
IConfiguration["Data:DB"]
```

For more information on how to do this: [ASP.NET Core Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

Then pass the connection string in your DBContext's constructor.

This is how I do it in one of my applications with the same scenario.

Your will need to modify your T4 Template (NameOfModel.Context.tt) in the project that has the EDMX file:

Add this line to the constructor:

```
: base(ConfigHelper.GetConnectionString("<#=container.Name#>"))
```

Where ConfigHelper.GetConnectionString is a static class with a method to read the configuration from the appsettings.json like mentioned before.

Comment: As i said earlier, my DbContext constructor does not receive any arguments. It calls the base constructor with the name of the connection string
`Context():base("name="MyEntity"){}`

Comment: You will have to change the t4 template.  I showed you how

Comment: The Context constructor is in a .Net framework dll while the configuration is in  another project. How can the `ConfigHelper` read the configuration? the .net core project is dependent on the .net framework project

Comment: You need to create a DLL with the ConfigHelper class.  in .NET Core dependencies are Injected.  So you should use dependency injection to assign the IConfiguration coming from the ASP.NET Core configuration.

Comment: ASP.NET Core is very different than other versions of .NET.  You will have to forget the "traditional" .NET way of doing things.

Comment: You need to learn how .NET Core Configuration works and how Dependency Injection works. You will need to understand both to do what you want.

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro This change seems to hose the edmx? I get a "An error occurred while initializing the frame's content System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object." when I try open the edmx after making that change.